# Dummy data update before model update

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have a model (my.model). Also i have a data file which will populate this table. There is another model (test.model), which has a many2one field referencing to (my.model). The code is below:

My model: testModel.py

```
Class myModel(models.Model):
      _name="my.model"
      name = fields.Char('Name',default=None)

Class testModel(models.Model):
      _inherits='stock.location'

      location_role_id = fields.Many2one('my.model','location role',required= True,default=1)
```

The data file to populate table is (my_model_data.xml)

```
<openerp>
    <data>
       <record id="default" model="my.model">
          <field name="name">Default</field>
       </record>

       <record id="default_new" model="my.model">
          <field name="name">New Value</field>
       </record>
    </data>
 </openerp>
```

Now when i install my module. It creates the table (my_model), but i have to put a default value to many2one field, Which will reference to first id of the table (my_model). 
But it gives me error that referenced id to my_model table does not exist. Integrity error constraint foreign key.

So what i found is, odoo creates the table, then update the other table and at last populate the table. So while creating the many2one field it does not find the id because the table is populated after this step.

Is there a way to insert or populate table before updating the many2one field.so that i can reference the default value to 1.

Thanks,

Comment: yes you can override the `create` method of `stock.location`, but are you sure the data file is being loaded how did you declare it in your `__openerp__.py` file

Comment: Hi danidee,  i want to populate table based on xml. Yes, data file loads and insert the value in table. But that process is done after updating stock.location. i declared the data file in [`data`] field of __openerp__.py